# Ajax is not working issue

Tags: php, ajax

I double check my code, and I couldn't find which part I did wrong. Every time, I click the button, it doesn't retrieve the file from my generate.php

INDEX.PHP

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function myLoad(){
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }else{
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                        document.getElementById('par').innerHTML == xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open('GET', 'generate.php', true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="par"></div>
        <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="myLoad();">
    </body>
</html>
```

GENERATE.PHP

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello';
?>
```

Comment: Are you fine with using jQuery?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It depends on your needs. For educational purposes `jQuery`, `prototype` and so on _must_ not be used. Good javascript developer definitely is good jQuery developer after reading its documentation but not contrary. For development you _should_ use jQuery but not necessarily (e.g. all you need is to make request and update existing data).

Answer (score 7):

```
document.getElementById('par').innerHTML == xmlhttp.responseText;
                                         ^ // here is problem it should be =

document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: +1 First time I've seen this its usually the other way around

Comment: OH! THANKS! I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Musa What's other way around?

Comment: @PraveenKumar `if (x = y)` --> `if (x == y)`

Comment: @Musa The first one always `true`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar The first one is a bug. :D Technically speaking you are correct, of course.

Answer (score 1):

#### Typo Here:

```
document.getElementById('par').innerHTML == xmlhttp.responseText;
------------------------------------------^ // Make it just =
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code in index.php file. i m sure it will solve your problem and when you click on button it call 'Hello' from generate.php file.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function myLoad()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()               {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("par").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","generate.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="myLoad();">
    <div id="par"></div>
</body>
</html>
```